# Get the difference between two strings

Tags: php, wildcard

I am creating a wildcard search/replace function and need to find the difference between two strings. I have tried some functions like `array_diff` and `preg_match`, browsed my way trough ~10 google pages with no solution.

I have a *simple* solution right now, but want to implement support for unknown value before wildcard

Here's what I got:

```
function wildcard_search($string, $wildcard) {
    $wildcards = array();
    $regex = "/( |_|-|\/|-|\.|,)/";
    $split_string = preg_split($regex, $string);
    $split_wildcard = preg_split($regex, $wildcard);
    foreach($split_wildcard as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($split_string[$key]) && $split_string[$key] != $value) {
            $wildcards[] = $split_string[$key];
        }
    }

    return $wildcards;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$str1 = "I prefer Microsoft products to Apple but love Linux"; //original string
$str2 = "I prefer * products to * but love *"; //wildcard search
$value = wildcard_search($str1, $str2);
//$value should now be array([0] => "Microsoft", [1] => "Apple", [2] => "Linux");

shuffle($value);
vprintf('I prefer %s products to %s but love %s', $value);
// now we can get all kinds of outputs like:
// I prefer Microsoft products to Linux but love Apple
// I prefer Apple products to Microsoft but love Linux
// I prefer Linux products to Apple but love Microsoft
// etc..
```

I want to implement support for unknown value before the wildcard.

Example:

```
$value = wildcard_search('Stackoverflow is an awesome site', 'Stack* is an awesome site');
// $value should now be array([0] => 'overflow');
// Because the wildcard (*) represents overflow in the second string
// (We already know some parts of the string but want to find the rest)
```

Could this be done without to much hassle with *hundreds of loops* etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd change your function to use [`preg_quote`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote) and replace the escaped `\*` character with `(.*?)` instead:

```
function wildcard_search($string, $wildcard, $caseSensitive = false) {
    $regex = '/^' . str_replace('\*', '(.*?)', preg_quote($wildcard)) . '$/' . (!$caseSensitive ? 'i' : '');

    if (preg_match($regex, $string, $matches)) {
        return array_slice($matches, 1); //Cut away the full string (position 0)
    }

    return false; //We didn't find anything
}
```

**Example**:

```
<?php
    $str1 = "I prefer Microsoft products to Apple but love Linux"; //original string
    $str2 = "I prefer * products to * but love *"; //wildcard search
    var_dump( wildcard_search($str1, $str2) );

    $str1 = 'Stackoverflow is an awesome site';
    $str2 = 'Stack* is an awesome site';
    var_dump( wildcard_search($str1, $str2) );

    $str1 = 'Foo';
    $str2 = 'bar';
    var_dump( wildcard_search($str1, $str2) );
?>
```

**Output**:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "Microsoft"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Apple"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Linux"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "overflow"
}
bool(false)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/87823)